# Working Directory: null Environment: null when trying to call compiled FFMPEG in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mp3

I have the compiled FFMPEG file. I try to combine an image and an audio clip to form a video clip. Function to combine those two are: ffmpeg -i /mnt/sdcard/KaraokeVideos/allmapeople.mp3 -i /mnt/sdcard/KaraokeVideos/Penguins.jpg /mnt/sdcard/KaraokeVideos/video_finale.mpg.

I have used that in the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Process process;
    String command, text;

    // load the library - name matches jni/Android.mk-jj
    //static {

        //System.loadLibrary("ffmpeg");
    //}



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            Execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } 

    private void Execute() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -i /mnt/sdcard/KaraokeVideos/allmapeople.mp3 -i /mnt/sdcard/KaraokeVideos/Penguins.jpg /mnt/sdcard/KaraokeVideos/video_finale.mpg");
        p.getInputStream();
    }
```

But I get this exception in logcat:

```
01-10 18:44:24.209: W/System.err(31790): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [ffmpeg, -i, /mnt/sdcard/KaraokeVideos/allmapeople.mp3, -i, /mnt/sdcard/KaraokeVideos/Penguins.jpg, /mnt/sdcard/KaraokeVideos/video_finale.mpg] Working Directory: null Environment: null
01-10 18:44:24.239: W/System.err(31790):    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
01-10 18:44:24.239: W/System.err(31790):    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:168)
01-10 18:44:24.239: W/System.err(31790):    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:241)
01-10 18:44:24.249: W/System.err(31790):    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:184)
01-10 18:44:24.249: W/System.err(31790):    at com.mindtherobot.samples.ndkfoo.MainActivity.Execute(MainActivity.java:47)
01-10 18:44:24.259: W/System.err(31790):    at com.mindtherobot.samples.ndkfoo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
01-10 18:44:24.259: W/System.err(31790):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-10 18:44:24.269: W/System.err(31790):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-10 18:44:24.269: W/System.err(31790):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
01-10 18:44:24.269: W/System.err(31790):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
01-10 18:44:24.289: W/System.err(31790):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-10 18:44:24.289: W/System.err(31790):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
01-10 18:44:24.299: W/System.err(31790):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 18:44:24.309: W/System.err(31790):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 18:44:24.309: W/System.err(31790):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-10 18:44:24.319: W/System.err(31790):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 18:44:24.319: W/System.err(31790):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-10 18:44:24.329: W/System.err(31790):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-10 18:44:24.339: W/System.err(31790):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-10 18:44:24.339: W/System.err(31790):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 18:44:24.359: W/System.err(31790): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
01-10 18:44:24.359: W/System.err(31790):    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
01-10 18:44:24.369: W/System.err(31790):    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
01-10 18:44:24.379: W/System.err(31790):    ... 19 more
01-10 18:44:24.699: D/gralloc_goldfish(31790): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

What is wrong here, any help would be great!

Comment: can you advice me to compile ffmpeg in windows using cygwin.. to create .so files ???

Comment: this will help you: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/........Any comments about my question?

Comment: i know how to use ndk and i have worked ndk projects.. but in case of ffmpeg i am getting issues..  says no link between library's...

Comment: I think .c file is not compiled properly..Do you see the .so file under libs?

Comment: no .. do you have working source ?

Comment: yes I do, it is same as the link that I gave you, If you want I can mail the source.

Comment: rajeshandroiddeveloper@gmail.com... thats my mail id..